# Find partial string in row using regex using SSIS Script component

Tags: c#, regex, ssis

I am parsing an elections contest file and I need to identify certain races using partial phrases only associated with those races. The only way I can figure out how to do this is using REGEX, which I have almost no experience with.

Consider the following column in a SQL table, I would need each of these to be captured by the REGEX. There are numerous other contests in there that don't need to be captured as well as others that do that may have a different integer (propositions for example):

```
contesttitlecleaned
ATTORNEY GENERAL
CORPORATION COMMISSIONER
Race Statistics
REGISTERED VOTERS - TOTAL
Registration & Turnout
State Rep Dst 1 (vote for 2)
STATE REP. - DIST. 14 (ELECT 2) STATE REP DIST 14
State Senator Dist. 7                                   
US Rep Dst 1
Proposition 304
BALLOTS CAST - BLANK
BALLOTS CAST - TOTAL
```

This is my current code:

```
    public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    string keywords1 = "\b(attorney|ballots|corporation|proposition|statistics|regist|state|US)";


    if (Regex.Match(Row.contesttitlecleaned, keywords1, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Success)
    {
        Row.ctkeyword1 = Row.contesttitlecleaned;
    }
}
```

The regex is not picking up any of the key words

Comment: sorry, that was a  trial and error mistake. Changed.

Comment: What are you trying to get?

Comment: Each of those to go into the ctkeyword1 row. There are 600+ other rows that I don't need. This is an example so there are many different versions of the above contests that I would need to capture.

Comment: Are you working for an election tampering firm ?

Comment: Have you tried playing with a Regex Tester?   https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+tester&oq=regex+tester&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.2143j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8